# Redirect logged-in User to Profile Page (to Enable 2-factor) in Laravel Jetstream / Fortify?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I've been looking into a way to redirect a logged in user to their Profile Page if the user does not have 2-factor auth enabled for their profile (ideally would like to do this for all routes).  **I am using Laravel 8, Fortify and Jetstream.**

It looks like 2-factor is not enabled if **two_factor_secret** & **two_factor_recovery_codes** in the **users** table are NULL for the User in question.  It is at least enabled if those DB columns are not NULL.  One place to possibly check looks like in:

```
/app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php
```

It by default sets:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
```

verifies the login, and then I do some housekeeping if they are authenticated.

By default, there is a return $user at the end of the script.

I can check to see if $user->two_factor_secret in not null in the script, so if it is possible to change the route on the fly somehow there that might work, at least a far as the initial login is concerned, but I would prefer to check their 2-factor enabled status (just the status, not a code) for every route in the app.  It isn't really clear to me how to do that ?  In a ServiceProvider somewhere or in the routes/web.php, etc.  I guess it is possible to wrap all of my routes in a group somehow, and they check the 2-step status in the routes/web.php somehow before processing the requested route ?

Any help would be appreciated.  There are really two options.  Just a warning and redirection to the Profile Page (/user/profile) upon login if they do not have 2-step activated (i.e. DB field populated with data), and then the more global option to always redirect to the profile page for any route if they do not have 2-step enabled (that would prevent navigation to any other page than the profile page).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) which can be applied to a group of routes which will determine if the authenticated user has `2FA`enabled.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HasTwoFactorAuthEnabled
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (is_null(Auth::user()->two_factor_secret)) {
            return redirect(route('user.profile.2fa'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In the above, if the value of `two_factor_secret` for the authenticated user is `null`, we assume it is not enabled and therefore redirect the user. Otherwise the request continues to the next middleware.

As you likely don't want to perform this check on all your `HTTP` requests or even all your `web` requests, you will want to register the middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'has2FaEnabled' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasTwoFactorAuthEnabled::class,
];
```

Then you can apply the middleware to individual routes, or a group of routes. For example;

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['has2FaEnabled']], function () {
    Route::get('/profile', ProfileController::class);
});
```

Now, whether or not you want/should redirect users if they have not enabled `2FA` is really down to your use-case and the type of application. If security is important to you or the data managed within your application is sensitive then enforcing `2FA` might be a good idea. Otherwise if you're just providing `2FA` features for additional security, I might recommend avoiding forcing users to enable it and instead simply recommend that users enable it or prevent access to certain 'sensitive' features if it is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks.  Have not tried the recommendation yet, but seems like the "correct" to implement that.  It actually is a sensitive application (e.g. HIPAA protected data), so I would prefer to have the option of only allowing access to just the profile page after login if they do not have 2Fa enabled.  The Enable button is on the profile page.  I'll play around with your recommendations and F/U about that.

Comment: BTW, not sure if you are available for freelance work, but sounds like you have some good familiarity with Laravel.  I'm just learning how to use it and would really like to have a good understanding before I get off on some tangents and have to rewrite things later.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak the Middleware a little bit to get it to work on my setup:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class HasTwoFactorAuthEnabled extends Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if (is_null(Auth::user()->two_factor_secret)) {
            session(['modal_message' => 'You Need to Enable 2-Factor Auth']);
            return redirect(route('profile.show'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Although that seems to work, in web.php, just as a test:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['has2FaEnabled']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('welcome');
});
```

There is a thing to handle the modal message in my layouts/app.blade.php.  I actually started testing the use of Spatie's CSP package also, which is why there is a nonce there, although I'd like to avoid using inline scripts eventually.

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="true" tabindex='-1'>

    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body"></div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="uibuttonsmallred" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
$modal_message = session('modal_message', false);
if ($modal_message !== false) {
?>
    <script nonce= "{{ csp_nonce() }}">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html('<?php echo $modal_message ?>');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

That redirects to the profile page, which is profile.show on my system.  I should be able to handle the rest.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if that is correct, but that seems to work now, i.e. the 'use' statements in the Middleware ?

Comment: Probably need to add a "catch-all" Route at the end to capture routes that are by-passed, and I might want to add a modal message on the redirect also ?

Comment: Edited my answer so that there is a modal message with the redirect.  That is handled in the app layout.