# Laravel 8 Redirect Authenticated User Until Data is Changed

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect

Seems like there are a lot of posts related to authentication and redirects, but I can't seem to find exactly what I need. I feel like it should be simple.

So, we have a system whereby we want users to enable 2FA and change their passwords every 60 days. We are using Laravel 8 with Jetstream. I am doing a check on login (via modifying config/fortify.php), which works fine, if the password needs to be changed or if they don't have 2FA they get directed on login to their profile page and they see a message saying they need to update their details.

The problem is they can then navigate to any other page without updating anything. Ideally I want them to be redirected back to the profile page until they update their info.

We have the routes inside a middleware group:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function() {
  routes here
});
```

I thought I could just add a check before any routes load using Auth::user(), but the array is empty and therefore any vars accessed are null.

Auth::users()->role;

I was hoping for something like:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function() {
  if (pass needs resetting and current route isn't profile) {
    redirect('/profile');
  }
});
```

I'm assuming that Laravel doesn't authenticate the user until after the middleware has run? Not sure, but that would explain the null values.

So, how would you guys accomplish this? Do I need to modify a controller instead? I just need the user to stay on their profile page until they have updated their data, then they can proceed as normal.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You should create a route middleware for this purpose.

Comment: OK, I found this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68147368/redirect-logged-in-user-to-profile-page-to-enable-2-factor-in-laravel-jetstrea?rq=1

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it working now. It really was easy.  lol.